Flutter - How to turn off the suggested emojis when searching for emoji on the keyboard, when focusing on the input field?
I encountered a problem in the application I developed with Flutter. In the text field;

I focused on the text box.
I entered emojis on the keyboard.
I typed the emoji name in the Search emoji text box on the keyboard.
Then I selected an emoji from the results and added it to the box.
Then I tapped the text box once.

The feature I want is available in the iOS for WhatsApp mobile app. I think they have done a special work.
Thank you in advance for the help.
I want the emoji suggestions on the keyboard to turn off after the last step, but I have no idea how to do it because I haven't found a source.

In Flutter, the emoji suggestion behavior is controlled by the keyboard software on the user's device, not directly by Flutter.
However You can specify the TextInputType as TextInputType.text and set the keyboardType and textInputAction properties. Additionally, using the SmartQuotesType.disabled and SmartDashesType.disabled properties can also help refine input behavior.
